# Dataset of lines at n miles from the coast

Tags: data-request, geospatial, python, oceanographic

I'm using [Folium](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium) to generate some interactive maps with ocean data. One of the restrictions I am facing is that the objects, I plot has to be at-least at `5, 6, .., n` miles from the coast, hence I am looking for points or lines that meet the criteria.

Where can I find such a data?

Comment: It sounds like you want a multi-ring, fixed-distance buffer of the landmasses. I don't know if you can find this data already existing, but it should be pretty simple to generate. Try asking on gis.stackexchange.com if you want help with that.

Comment: check out this search of noaa data for "offshore" https://data.noaa.gov/dataset/?q=offshore&sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&page=1

Comment: As per @albert, https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/distfromcoast/ is probably the best source. https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/how-to-calculate-boundary-around-all-land-on-earth asks a similar question, and https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/STACK/bc-buffer-land.pl is one of my attempts to parse the NASA data. Be careful, though: inland seas are NOT included in these calculations. I've made more thorough calculations using GRASS if you need them, but, once you start including rivers, it gets fairly strange.

Comment: Answer in comments is now community wiki

Answer (score 0):

As per [@albert](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/dataset-of-lines-at-n-miles-from-the-coast#comment17737_13910), https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/distfromcoast is probably the best source.

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/… asks a similar question,

and https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/STACK/… is one of my attempts to parse the NASA data.

Be careful, though: inland seas are NOT included in these calculations. I've made more thorough calculations using GRASS if you need them, but, once you start including rivers, it gets fairly strange.

Comment: your github link is broken

Answer (score 0):

I would take the USGS shoreline data then buffer it as needed.  Pretty easy task just depending upon the accuracy needed. Not all shore data is created equal. ;)

Comment: can you provide more information here? particularly around buffering?